# Adding Hyperlinks via Ribbon has incorrect behaviour

Tags: 2013, site-collection, hyperlink

My fellow administrators and I are stumped on this one:

One of our coworkers (who is a Site Collection Administrator) was trying to add a hyperlink to another page in their departments site collection. Normally to do this, you edit a page, add link "from SharePoint" and then depending on the page layout you can select Browse or it'll just open up a content view of your site collection. What happens for her is that rather than opening a contents view, it opens a list WebPart view instead.

The problem only happens on her departments Site Collection. When tested on any other site collection there is the normal expected behavior. I am unable to duplicate the issue on any other Site Collection Admin account.

Below is an example of the steps she takes*, however its happens on any "add links" option. If anyone has some insight or could help me troubleshoot I would greatly appreciate it.

## Add to site navigation

#### Site Settings

[image: Select 'Navigation' in SiteSettings]

#### Select 'Add Link...'

[image: Add Link]

#### Select 'Browse'

[image: Browse]

#### Resulting page

[image: Result]

#### Expected Page

[image: Expected]

*I've changed some of the words in the images to prevent information leaks but the results are the same either way.

Comment: just to strike off the possible causes, is there a master page attached to this site collection? Or maybe, the user who is a site collection admin have the default master page edited? If so, can you switch to the default master page and try this again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Neepu for trying to help, but we couldn't find the cause of the issue... However, we did fix the issue.

Turns out that the view that was showing was a list view. So we tried to delete the list view that was linking ("Latest Aerial Photos") from the list ("Employee Engagement Survey Results") and the bug was fixed.